# How can I activate a button's Click command on Enter key press?

Tags: silverlight, mvvm, command, prism, login-control

I'm developing an app using SL Prism and MEF using MVVM.

I have my login page which currently contains a username and password textbox and a single login button. The code for my button is as below:

```
<Button x:Name="signInButton" Content="Sign In" cal:Click.Command="{Binding loginCommand}"/>
```

What I'm struggling with is wiring up the textbox so that if the user hits enter the loginCommand executes. I've done a lot of googling and can't seem to find any answers that cope with MVVM.

I tried adding a KeyDown event handler to the stackpanel the controls are within. However from the code behind the only thing I can achieve is setting the focus to the button.

```
private void StackPanel_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Key == Key.Enter)
    {
        this.signInButton.Focus();
        e.Handled = true;
    } 
}
```

How can I achieve the goal of the enter key being pressed causing the loginCommand to be executed?

Many Thanks
James

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the [Automation Peer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms747327.aspx) classes to press it. This will then work with an MVVM ICommand like the one you have:

```
ButtonAutomationPeer peer =
  new ButtonAutomationPeer( someButton );

IInvokeProvider invokeProv =
  peer.GetPattern( PatternInterface.Invoke )
  as IInvokeProvider;

invokeProv.Invoke();
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to add trigger on `KeyDown` event with parameter(DependencyProperty) - command that should be invoked. If key is `Key.Enter` then simply invoke command.

Answer (score -1):

Can you just call the click method? For instance inside of your capture of the Enter button where "this.signInButton.Focus();" is, put "signInButton_Click(null, null);" to fire the button's click method directly.

Comment: I think you missed the `cal:Click.Command="{Binding loginCommand}"` bit in the example. He is using MVVM ICommand binding and not code-behind. There is no `signInButton_Click(null, null)` to call

Comment: @Basti: SLL supports codebehind like the signInButton_Click(null, null) you suggest, but the MVVM pattern frowns upon using code-behind in preference to bindings (data and command). Cheers

Answer (score -1):

You can add KeyBinding in xaml for specific commands like this:

```
 <Button Command="{Binding TestCommand}" Content="Test">
        <Button.InputBindings>
            <KeyBinding Command="{Binding TestCommand}" Key="F2" />
        </Button.InputBindings>
    </Button>
```

This way the KeyBinding works if your Button is focused. If you want your KeyBinding to be available in a larger scope, you can add the KeyBinding for example to a Window ( Window.KeyBindings ) or any other element.

Comment: There is no `KeyBinding` in Silverlight